# Smart TV Applications

Tags: jakarta-ee, samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

what are smart tv apps? is they  are list of links at the some servers. So starting a App means open a webpage in a browser.

if then can we develop app using java for smart tv or whether it can only develop by vendor specific SDK

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Common apps for smart tv is fully client-side with HTML5/CSS and JavaScript but it still can retrieve data from server using AJAX.

So basically it like building web pages without any webserver, just using browser as the client. No PHP/JSP/ASP or any server side scripting in the application code.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of vendor specific SDK's. For instance, Panasonic has their [VIERA Connect](http://developer.vieraconnect.com/). The apps themselves are mostly HTML/JavaScript based, but with API access to the device specific capabilities.

The answer will of course vary from one device to another.

Although I don't know what a generally agreed upon definition of a smart tv would be, I suppose a built in browser would be some kind of minimum. So even if a lot of vendors have their own thing they call apps, you should be able to build something web-based that'd work for most devices (being limited, then, to what can be done from the browser).

Comment: whether these apps use any other than html css and javascript

Answer (score 2):

Most of the smart TV uses simple HTML5, JavaScript, Jquery based app.

Some Tv also Support server based app where app resides on a server an can be called by the TV through widget like LG and vizio app,

But SDKS are somehow required to make launching widgets like in case of samsung and lg